# Is it possible to 'pretend' a site is a third party to test functionality if 3rd party cookies are blocked?

Tags: firefox, cookies, selenium-webdriver

I do automation testing for a company that is trying to implement a single sign on via an iFrame; a third party site will include our page in an iFrame and we will do an authorization.

We had to rework the way this worked because of Firefox defaulting to 3rd Party Cookies being off. For manual testing, we have hosted the page on a different domain, but this domain requires certain usernames and passwords we cannot expose in code, so this is difficult to automate.

Is there a way I can trick Firefox into thinking that mydomain.com is not actually mydomain.com? This sounds impossible, because if I can trick Firefox into thinking I'm actually on mydomain2.com, then I can effectively just put on a 3rd party cookie, but since I'm doing it on my own instance of Firefox, are there any settings I can change in my profile to confuse it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is incredibly easy and we do this all the time.

Log onto the test machine (the computer that will be running the browser) and edit the hosts file, located in c:\windows\system\drivers\etc

Add an entry for the site you wish to be confused, using a different domain name but the correct IP address. Because it's a different domain, it'll look like a third party site, but because the IP address is the same, the requests will actually be sent to the same web server.

Example:

Assume your web server is running on the local host (which has address 127.0.0.1)

Add host entries for

```
127.0.0.1   FirstPartyDomain.com
127.0.0.1   ThirdPartyDomain.com
```

Access your site via http://FirstPartyDomain.com

Site contains an iFrame

```
<iframe src="ThirdPartyDomain.com/SetNastyCookies">
```

The request in the iFrame will go to the same server (local host) but in the context of a third party site.

Answer (score 0):

What about using DNSMasq? Most open-sourced routers such as DD-WRT support this option. If you need to test it via https, you could also temporarily store security certificate exceptions as well during your testing.